# 6TO Toshiba hard drive slowing after a couple of minutes

Tags: hard-drive, performance, toshiba-hard-drive

I have a very large amount of data to save to this hard drive (~3TB) in packets of approximately 10GB.

- Transfer rate begin at ~20-30MB/sec for a couple of minutes
- Then it slow down to max. 5MB/sec

I have searched for someone having the same issue but can't find an answer over the internet..Here is a screenshot of progress bar:

[image: progress bar transfer rate slowing down]

Thanks for your help friends

**EDIT:**
Here is the results of my tests in hdTune:

[image]

Comment: How are you transferring the data?

Comment: How are the drives connected? All to a direct SATA port, or any usb or network?

Comment: @Xen2050 All are connected  by sata 3. harrymc: how ? Drag n drop lol

Answer (score 1):

What you're likely experiencing is caching. The system writes to either RAM or an internal fast piece of storage inside the hard disk until it fills up.

The advantage of this is for a short read/write operation that is smaller than the cache. The cache will partially fill, and whatever process (or the user) was writing to the disk can go back to what they were doing earlier. All the while in the background, the cache is being emptied to the physical disk.

Unfortunately, for writes that are significantly larger than the cache, this doesn't really have an advantage - especially because after it's done, the cache *still* has to be dumped (it was filled and then the disk was running at max capacity, there was no way to dump it). This is why you need to **always eject drives before removing them**. The eject process tells the disk to empty its cache before it tells you it's "safe to remove hardware"

That being said - those disk speeds look painfully slow. What is the source of the files? Earlier today I had an rsync (data transfer over the network) running to an HDD at ~110MB/s after the caches filled up. It's possible that either you have a bottleneck somewhere, or the transfer mediums (source and/or destination) are busy with other things. Is one of them running the operating system? Are you browsing photos/videos on one of the drives?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, the source drive is SSD and none of them run the operating system. Also, I have checked that no other tasks on computer is using HDD bandwidth. Also, I update my answer to show test results I am making